# How to generate a random boolean in Dart

Tags: dart, random, boolean

I've seen people generate random booleans in Dart before, but I can't remember how to do it.

*I just found the answer so I'm adding it below Q&A style.*

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can generate a random boolean with [Random](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-math/Random-class.html):

```
import 'dart:math';

final randomNumberGenerator = Random();
final randomBoolean = randomNumberGenerator.nextBool();
```

If you want to generate a stream of random booleans you can continue to call `nextBool()`.